# Getting filenames from a directory

Tags: c#, directory

```
string[] klasorlistesi = Directory.GetFiles(path+"//notlar//");
foreach (string eleman in klasorlistesi)
    listBox1.Items.Add(eleman);
```

I'm getting the datas from an array with through above code inside listBox.
BTW the file has no extension.

My question is:
**I want to appear the file as only `"not"` instead of `"C:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\not"` inside the Listbox.**

Also, I tried a thing like below code, but it's not working:

```
System.IO.Path.GetFileName(@"C:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\not");
```

How can I do that?

Comment: "It's not working" isn't a good description of what's actually happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like

```
listbox1.Items.Add(eleman.Substring(eleman.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to change your last line to:

```
listBox1.Items.Add(new FileInfo(eleman).Name);
```

Should do the trick.

Another option that you can do is to extract it yourself like this, but it looks a bit messier. Probably a bit faster, but in your case you should not notice.

```
listBox1.Items.Add(eleman.Substring(eleman.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1));
```

Comment: I think thats "the better way" than mine, but it may be slow, because it reads all the file infos from the disk...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
string s = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(@"C:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\not");
```

Result is not